# RabbitMQ Pull all messages from queue

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I have a system that wraps RabbitMQ using erlang and the erlang client. We have the occasional situation where a subscriber goes down and messages queue. We will be implementing a dead-letter queue in the near future but I would like to implement a tool in the mean time to bind to a given queue and PULL all messages. I can then push them off somewhere else and replay them when the subscriber comes back online. However, I am having a hard time determining the best way to do this with the Rabbit tutorials/docs/ Mainly because the tutorials are a bit lacking for erlang clients.

Does anybody have experience with this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is make the queue set to **not** auto delete.  That way the queue will stay alive when the subscriber goes down.  The exchange will continue to push messages to the queue which will store them until the subscriber comes back up and starts reading again.

Comment: Thanks @robthewolf. We actually do have a durable queue. However, these queues are growing large enough that we would like to purge the queues but not lose the data. Thus why I would like to pull the messages from the queue then purge. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you need to purge them because it is tying up resources and causing your system to slow down? Otherwise if it is just because the queue looks too big then I am not sure I see the need here.  I am aware the RMQ works best with empty queues, I am pretty sure that this is limited to the individual queues, so one large queue should not affect the rest of the RMQ system.

Comment: I have just edited my answer as I meant set the queue to not auto delete.  Durability of the queue, exchange and message persistence is only relevant if you have a problem with the RMQ server going down as opposed to the subscriber.  From you comment I am guessing you are already doing it that way but I just wanted to draw attention to my earlier error.

Comment: We actually do need to purge the queues. We have actually been faced with several situations where we needed to purge the queues via the RMQ console because we gathered 250+k messages on each of 4 clustered servers and we saw a significant slowdown of message delivery. Obviously, this loss of data is less than ideal.